# VBA Error 438, PPT slide movement using values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

With the code below I am receiving the 438 error when I try to move a slide to a section that has already been created. Last 4 lines of the code. 
Sorry if this code is not clear, but I am new to VBA.

```
Private Sub CopyandPastetoPPT(Counter As Integer)
Dim NextShape As Integer
Dim IssueName As String
Dim IssueDesc As String
Dim CfoNumber As String
Dim IndName As String
Dim Cat1 As Variant

    IssueName = Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Cells(Counter, 1)
    IssueDesc = Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Cells(Counter, 3)
    CfoNumber = Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Cells(Counter, 5)
    IndName = Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Cells(Counter, 7)
    Cat1 = Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Cells(Counter, 9)

    Set PP_Slide = PP_File.Slides(Counter + 1)

    PP_Slide.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
         Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=276, Height:=59

    NextShape = PP_Slide.Shapes.Count

    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = IssueName
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = vbBlack
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle

    PP_Slide.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
         Left:=276, Top:=0, Width:=153, Height:=59

    NextShape = PP_Slide.Shapes.Count

    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = IssueDesc
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = vbWhite
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    PP_Slide.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=199, Top:=59, Width:=77, Height:=30

    NextShape = PP_Slide.Shapes.Count

    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CfoNumber
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 10
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = False
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = vbBlack
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).Line.Visible = False

    PP_Slide.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
        Left:=597, Top:=507, Width:=123, Height:=18

    NextShape = PP_Slide.Shapes.Count

    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = IndName
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 10
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic = True
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = False
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = vbBlack
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    PP_Slide.Shapes(NextShape).Line.Visible = False

    If Cat1 = "Center Consoles" Then

    PP_Slide.MoveToSection "Center Consoles"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `MoveToSection` method - it's `MoveToSectionStart`

Comment: What if I do not want it to move to the start of a section, but as the last slide within it?

Comment: Not sure, as I'm an Excel guy, but perhaps you could use the `MoveTo` method in conjunction with the `SectionProperties.FirstSlide` method to get the index of the first slide in the next section, and move before it?

Comment: Thanks, trying to move the section to the slides instead of the slides to the section now.

Comment: Its' been a while since I played with this, but Section has a SlidesCount property. Move your slide to the first slide of the section, get the SlidesCount of the section, then use your new slide's .MoveTo method to move it to the index of the first slide in the section + an offset that you derive from SlidesCount